# Error in parsing the JSON response in JQuery, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova

I am getting following as the JSON response but some indexes are having spaces like 'Employee Id'. That's why I am unable to parse it. Can anyone suggest the way to parse it  in JavaScript?

```
{
    "Employees": [
        {
            "Employee": {
                "Employee ID": "777",
                "Short Name": "abc",
                "First name": null,
                "Middle name": null,
                "Last name": null,
                "Designation": "Senior Engineer",
                "Ext-1": null,
                "Ext-2": null,
                "Mobile-1": null,
                "Mobile-2": null,
                "Email": "a.b@gmail.com"
            }
        },
        {
            "Employee": {
                "Employee ID": "888",
                "Short Name": "xyz",
                "First name": null,
                "Middle name": null,
                "Last name": null,
                "Designation": "Test Lead",
                "Ext-1": null,
                "Ext-2": null,
                "Mobile-1": null,
                "Mobile-2": null,
                "Email": "c.d@gmail.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My code -

```
 function GetContacts() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: "http://. . . . . .",

        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {

            //alert(data.getString("Employee ID"));
            $.each(data, function(i, contactList) {

                alert('First Loop' + i);
                alert('First Loop' + contactList[0]);

                $.each(contactList, function(j, Contact) {
                    //alert('Second Loop'+Contact);
                    var fnalObj = Contact;
                    //alert(fnalObj);
                    //alert(fnalObj.["Employee"]["Employee ID"]);
                    //alert(Employees[j]["Employee"]["Email"]);
                    //alert(Employees[0]["Employee"]["Employee ID"]);
                    alert(fnalObj.Employee.Email);
                    alert(fnalObj.Employee.Designation);
                    alert(fnalObj.Employee.Ext - 1);
                    alert(fnalObj.Employee.Mobile - 1);
                });
            });
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Keys with spaces are no problem for the parser. `JSON.parse` and jQuery's parser will just work fine. See http://jsfiddle.net/4jqQw/ ... so the question is what is your actual problem?

Comment: I think you can use `Employees[0]["Employee"]["Employee ID"]` instead of `Employees[0].Employee.Employee ID`(which is not correct) , but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: I put your JSON into http://jsonlint.com and it comes up as valid JSON, so a parser shouldn't be breaking on this. What parser are you using? Would you please paste code from your parsing attempt as well as the error you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing is fine.

The problem is accessing the keys which are made of non-alhpanumeric characters.. like spaces, dashes etc..

These properties must be handled with the `[]` notation like this

```
alert(fnalObj.Employee['Employee ID']);
alert(fnalObj.Employee['Ext-1']);
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/h9sbn/

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do `fnalObj.Employee.Ext - 1`. The correct way to do it would be `fnalObj.Employee['Ext-1']`. Here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/naryad/VNXa5/1/

When using `fnalObj.Employee.Ext - 1`, it gets resolved to `undefined - 1` which in turn returns you `NaN`

Same applies to `fnalObj.Employee.Mobile - 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(contactList, function(j, Contact) {
    //alert('Second Loop'+Contact);
    var fnalObj = Contact;
    $.each(finalObj, function (key, value) {
        var newKey = key.replace(/[\s]\-/g, '_');
        delete finalObj[key];
        finalObj[newKey] = value;
    });
    //revised alerts here.
});
```